# React-testing-library how to test conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library

I'm new to react-testing, and I'm having problem with testing for this part of my code, because it is a conditional, and when I try to test it, it's assuming it didn't pass the conditional.

```
<div>
  {ranking?.map((player, index) => (
    <div key={ index }>
      <img src={ `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${player.picture}` } alt="player" />
      <h2 data-testid={ `player-name-${index}` }>{player.name}</h2>
      <h2 data-testid={ `player-score-${index}` }>{player.score}</h2>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

This is what I made to test it:

```
const playerInfo = [
  { name: 'Player 1', score: 10, img: 'player1.png' },
  { name: 'Player 2', score: 5, img: 'player2.png' },
  { name: 'Player 3', score: 15, img: 'player3.png' },
];
localStorage.setItem('ranking', JSON.stringify(playerInfo));

renderWithRouterAndRedux(<Ranking />);
const playerNames = screen.getAllByTestId(/player-name-\d+/g).map((elem) => elem.textContent);
const playerScores = screen.getAllByTestId(/player-score-\d+/g).map((elem) => Number(elem.textContent));

expect(playerNames).toEqual(['Player 3', 'Player 1', 'Player 2']);
expect(playerScores).toEqual([15, 10, 5]);
```

But as a result, I got this from the testing:

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="/player-name-\d+/g"]`